# Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed

Tags: npm, laravel-nova

I'm trying to install laravel-nova in my Laravel project located in a Vagrant VM
When I run the command `npm install` in the packages.json directory, I get the following error:

`` ⚠ The `/home/vagrant/suitpackages/nova-components/Dashboard/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
  ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
  ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
    at /home/vagrant/suitpackages/nova-components/Dashboard/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) ``

I tried to run:`sudo apt-get install libpng-dev` but libpng-dev is already installed.

Comment: Can someone help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install lib **libpng-dev**

On Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libpng-dev
```

On alpine (in most docker images):

```
apk add --update \
           bash
           libpng-dev \
           gcc \
           g++ \
           make
```

Than instal js dependencies:

```
npm run install
```